# Import a Groovy script into another Groovy Script at Runtime

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I have a Groovy file that looks like this (currently).

main.groovy

```
import org.packages.mystuff.JavaClassIAmUsing;
public class MyObject {

    def rate(item){
        def o = evaluate(new File (new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent),"CommonFunctions.groovy");
        println o.whoami();

    }
}
```

i have another groovy file called

CommonFunctions.groovy

```
def whoami() {return 'no body';}
```

I'm trying to include the *CommonFunctions* script in to *main* script, BUT the location of the script are not known at build time (i.e. i can not hardcode a absolute file path in the script or absoulte path of the java process in relation to where the scripts will be stored).

All i know is that the scripts will be together or at a location relative to the calling script (say sub directory).

I've attempted to try and location the calling script location, but i get the error

```
  No signature of method: MyObject.evaluate()
```

How can i referance this script, considering the main script is accessed at runtime using a *GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(File)* method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you want to do it this way, I think it would be much simpler to make a class of `CommonsFunctions` that you could instantiate normally and use everywhere.

However, it *is* possible to achieve what you want; with Groovy, there are not that many limitations...

There are two problems with your suggested solution:

1. getClass() inside your `MyObject` class naturally refers to ... the `MyObject` class, so your attempt to find the location of the script will fail. You're on the right track, but you need to resolve the script location using the surrounding Script class.
2. `evaluate` doesn't really work the way you think it does. The result of the `evaluate` method is the result of the script, not an instance of the `Script` class. One way to remedy this, is to rewrite the methods in `CommonFunction` as closure properties. These properties will be available in the shell `Binding` object when evaluating the script.

So, with these rewrites, you end up with something like this:

**main.groovy**

```
class MyObject {
    def scriptDir

    def rate(item) {
        def commonFunctionsScriptFile = new File(scriptDir, "CommonFunctions.groovy")
        def binding = new Binding()
        new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate(commonFunctionsScriptFile)
        println binding.variables.whoami()
    }
}

scriptFile = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path)
new MyObject(scriptDir: scriptFile.parentFile).rate(null)
```

Here, the script file location is resolved in the script, not in the inner class.

**CommonFunctions.groovy**

```
whoami = { 'no body' }
```

Here, `whoami` is no longer a method, but a closure property which will be added to the binding. Make sure that you *don't* prefix this property with `def`, since then it will be a local variable instead of a property added to the binding object.

Output after these rewrites is the expected: `no body`.